# Why dig wont work on 127.0.0.1?

Tags: networking, server, dns, dnsmasq

I am learning networking. I didn't understand working of dig.
When we query dig for an IP address it will query dnsmasq running on port 53 for an IP.

These commands are working

```
dig www.google.com
dig @127.0.1.1 www.google.com
```

But this is not working

```
dig @127.0.0.1 www.google.com
```

My expectation is that, this should work because a process running with some port can be accessed with any IP in 127.0.0.0/8. Can anyone explain why above command is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DNSMASQ binds to individual IP addresses, like every IP-responsive service (like webservers, `bind9` nameservers, etc.)

While your system *does* have 127.0.0.1, and 127.0.1.1 implicitly, they are still handled like individual IP addresses (just like 192.168.123.4 is not 192.168.123.6 and can't be implied to be).

The implication that 127.0.1.1 and 127.0.0.1 are the same doesn't work with direct-to-IP commands.  IN default systems, nowadays, `dnsmasq` is configured to bind to 127.0.1.1.  This is why in your systems with Network Manager on them, you see `127.0.1.1` in the `/etc/resolv.conf` file.

Unless you change the `dnsmasq` configuration, it will not be able to bind to 127.0.0.1 and won't listen to requests being routed to 127.0.0.1; it will, however, route requests to 127.0.1.1 per its configuration for address-to-bind-to.  (This is a limitation to the default configurations, yes, but is actually not a bad thing as you can give different 'local services' different local loopback IP addresses to listen to on your system, which makes listening on localhost for requests in packet sniffing, etc. a little easier to achieve.)